# Why is the :after element getting applied to every child element of the parent?

Tags: html, css, hierarchy, pseudo-element

I am applying an :after pseudoelement to my div's ID. 
The problem is that the pseudoelement gets added to every child element of the div's parent. 
I want the pseudoelement to appear only once, as it is stated(according to me), only one time, and that is before the div with the ID.
I am not explicitly adding a pseudoelement to any of the inside elements.
My div's html code is the following:

```
<div id="contactUs" style="background-image: url(<?php echo CFS()->get( 'section4_background');?>">

<div class="container">


    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-12">

            <h2><?php echo CFS()->get( 'section4_title1');?></h2>

            <h1 class="header"><?php echo CFS()->get( 'section4_title2');?></h1>

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-2"></div>

        <div class="col-sm-7">

            <?php echo do_shortcode('[contact-form-7 id="20" title="Formulario de contacto"]');?>

            <div class="row  bottom">

                <div class="col-sm-6">

                    <a href="tel:+1<?php echo CFS()->get( 'phone_number_link' );?>">

                        <img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_url').'/'; ?>img/general/phoneIcon.png" class="img-fluid icon">

                        <p class="phone"><?php echo CFS()->get( 'phone_number' );?></p>

                    </a>

                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-6">

                    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/Vivesincancerchihuahua/" target="_blank">

                        <img src="<?php echo bloginfo('template_url').'/'; ?>img/general/facebookIcon.png" class="img-fluid icon">

                    </a>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

And my pseudoelement's css is:

```
#contactUs :after{

content: "Read this -";
background-color: yellow;
color: red;
font-weight: bold;
```

}

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pRwyt.jpg)

Comment: try getting rid of the space: `#contactUs::after{` space is a child selector in CSS. although i dont know what it does with psuedoelements... should also be two `::`s

Comment: Thank you! It was the space after stating the ID. About the double semicolon, I know that that is the correct form, but I read that IE8 still does not support the double semicolon.

Comment: @mpen thank you so much for your help, I never thought the space afected.

Comment: @antoniovaldes IE8 no longer exists.